# Attach a click() event to the FaceBook 'Like' button?

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, iframe

I'd like to do something on the page when a user clicks 'Like'.

I thought something simple like the following would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.connect_widget_like_button clearfix like_button_no_like').live('click', function () {
            alert('clicked');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the iFrame that FaceBook supplies to add the Like button to the page:

```
<iframe 
    id="FBLike"
    src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.MySite.Com... blahblahblah" 
    scrolling="no" 
    frameborder="0" 
    style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" 
    allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

My script attempts to bind a click event to an anchor tag that is loaded into the iFrame when the page loads. It doesn't work though. Is there any way for me to get jQuery to recognise when this is clicked? Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Facebook API doesn't allows you to subscribe to the like clicking event, but it allows you to subscribe to the like happening event (fired when the like action is completed):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // like clicked
});
```

see [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe).

Comment: but this cannot be done in a tab, right? any other solutions like at http://www.facebook.com/901Tequila?v=ap4904458780 , where clicking on the like button redirects you to the pin wall?

Comment: This answer is only good when using their bloated SDK, and most people just use the iframe solution.

Comment: can we get unlike event also .. I tried this and it gives response only when we like,,

Comment: @StrawHat late answer but hope it will help others. Use edge.remove for unlike event.

Comment: `edge.create` and `edge.remove` JS SDK Events are deprecated. Is there any alternative to that @serg?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use JavaScript to access elements within an iframe that does not belong to the current URL, as I guess the domain you're using is not facebook.com you won't be able to attach an event to the like button in this way.

Answer (score 4):

Make a PHP (or whatever language you use) script to CURL the source from `http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.MySite.Com... blahblahblah`

Put the source from facebook into your html page, you can then you can do whatever you like in JavaScript/jQuery with the code from Facebook.

Some examples for CURL within PHP - http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Comment: It's also most likely to be against their TOS/policy.

Comment: I have serious doubts what something like that would work. It would make like button spamable and Facebook can not allow that.

Comment: No idea what their TOS are, obviously you would need to check.  @denis , curling the URL will produce the same result as viewing the page directly or as is displayed in an iframe.

Comment: This will never work. FB social plugins like the Like button must be used in an iframe. This is by design for security.

The social plugins allow for actions that use facebook.com session cookies, and because they are cross-domain iframes, the container page can't interact (or interfere) with them via JavaScript. The exception to this is by using controls that have been exposed by cross-domain communication code on the document inside the iframe (the facebook.com page containing the Like button). You can use `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', ...)` in that way.

Answer (score 2):

One can detect 'like' and 'unlike' event of facebook like button using `edge.create` and `edge.remove` respectively.

Comment: I was not aware of the `edge.remove` event.  Do you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.connect_widget_like_button clearfix like_button_no_like').live('click', function () {
            alert('clicked');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it would be nice if you add some explaination