# Facebook like button detect with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm writing an app. for Facebook using HTML and Javascript.  I'm trying to detect with javascript when the "Like" button on the Facebook page is clicked.  I don't want to embed a "Like" button on my app page as Facebook already has a "Like" button at the top of the page right after my company's name.
I'm using Facebook's iFrame to display my app, but I haven't found any examples in Javascript to catch the "Like" click event.

Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attach a click() event to the FaceBook 'Like' button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718964/attach-a-click-event-to-the-facebook-like-button)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is in an Iframe the **[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)** applies. You cannot access content cross-domain. It is a security violation.

Comment: Thanks that make sense, but then I'm not sure how this site is working. http://www.facebook.com/BobbiBrown    BobbiBrown is doing exactly what I want to do with the "Like" button.

Answer (score 0):

On Facebook Pages, this is done through the Static FBML app. However, Facebook phased it out on 18 March 2011, but pages using the app before that date (including BobbiBrown) will continue using it.