# how to subscribe to facebook like event for iframe Like method

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have integrated facebook Like button in my facebook application using the **iframe method**.

I am not able to subscribe to Like event, even using

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
      alert('You just liked '+href);
    });
```

I understand this works for `<fb:like` .. but this method opens a comment pop-up whenever Like button is clicked, which I don't want to happen. If this can be avoided (making it work like iframe method), I am happy using this method.

I referred to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718992

but not sure this is the issue.

Can anyone please guide?

Thanks

Simply stated, is it possible to use

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
      alert('You just liked '+href);
    });
```

for iframe method of integrating Like ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it opens a pop-up it means you are subscribed.
Edit the second line in the javascript code to call action after user clicks like (now it calls pop-up).

Comment: thanks for response, actually the problem is i don't want pop-up to appear after Like is clicked. It does not open for iframe method, but neither is the event fired in that case.